# Dreadful Google CSE error

Tags: search

We have several sites <strike>on a multisite structure</strike>, and almost all of them use [Google CSE](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_cse). However, some of these websites display the error "Refused to display 'http://www.google.com/cse?cx=...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. This behaviour happens only for a couple of sites. I have compared Google CSE settings, and they are identical. How can I fix this issue?

UPDATE: I've compared directory sizes from both sites and they were different, so I've tried removing the module from the site that doesn't work, and copying one from a site that does work; but no dice :S

Answer (score -1):

Doing a quick search on Google I found this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905169/when-did-google-search-start-sending-x-frame-options-sameorigin

I hope it helps.

Best regards,
David.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @David, thanks but that post is about 4 years old, while our problem is about 2 months old.